# magento 2 keep the applied filters in opened state

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, filter, multiselect

I wish to make changes in the layered navigation filter, so that all the applied filters are visible(opened state).
For example I am selecting red in color filter, all other options in color filter should be visible. Color filter collapsible behaviour should be open.